# EWS php e-mail set sender name

Tags: php, email, exchangewebservices

I send e-mails with ews-php library (exchange 2013) and try to set custom sender's name.

I use the code from the official api: http://jamesarmes.com/php-ews/doc/0.1/examples/email-send.html

```
$fromAddress = new EWSType_EmailAddressType();
$fromAddress->EmailAddress = 'email@server.de';
$fromAddress->Name = 'From Name';

$msg->From = new EWSType_SingleRecipientType();
$msg->From->Mailbox = $fromAddress;
```

So it should look like `"From Name <email@server.de>"`. Instead it's `"Email <email@server.de>"`

Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: can you provide a link to the api?

Comment: Is it this: https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews

Comment: Yes, I changed my question and added a link.